# MozillaVPN - Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: package-management

I am on 20.04.1 and trying to setup MozillaVPN using the command :

`sudo apt-get install mozillavpn`

Get below error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

mozillavpn : Depends: libqt5charts5 (>= 5.14.2-2) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-6) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-6) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-6) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5networkauth5 (>= 5.14.2-2) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-6) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-6) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5qmlmodels5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqt5svg5 (>= 5.14.2-2) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: libqt5quickcontrols2-5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtcharts (>= 5.14.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects (>= 5.14.2-2) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls (>= 5.14.2-2) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls2 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-extras (>= 5.14.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-layouts (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick-window2 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtquick2 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtqml-models2 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
              Depends: qml-module-qtqml (>= 5.14.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what could be the issue here ?

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: What was the source of `mozillavpn` package?

Comment: have tried that option already - doesn't work

Comment: source is https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/mozilla-vpn-client

Comment: Where in the world are you? The Mozilla VPN service is currently only available to users in the US, UK, Canada, New Zealand, Singapore, and Malaysia. See [this reference](https://news.itsfoss.com/mozilla-vpn-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add [official *Mozilla VPN* PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillacorp/+archive/ubuntu/mozillavpn) to the system and then install the package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillacorp/mozillavpn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mozillavpn
```

---

Notes:

1. The Mozilla VPN package currently is available [only](https://repology.org/project/mozillavpn/versions) for ArchLinux, the AUR [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mozillavpn) uses source code from the above PPA.
2. The above PPA has info notice on its page with text "Publishing has been disabled for this archive.", not sure what does it mean.

Comment: Download of mozilla vpn leads to that link. Tried those 3 commands and the third command is what gives the errors. Mine is a Ubuntu running on MacOS.

Comment: If you are bound & determined to install (from ppa) then simply add ppa & install mozillavpn as noted above. That''l give you the previous built version, 2.0.1-focal2. If you want the last unpublished build then on ppa page go to package Details > expand dropdown for mozillavpn (focal) and you'll find the .deb package. Download and install with apt (obviously needs ppa enabled